# Automated access to GA in google sheets not working?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-analytics

I have followed the tutorial, and all I am getting is 'No views (profiles) found'

I have a google sheet open and my GA.

Code from the tutorial:

```
function getFirstProfile() {
  var accounts = Analytics.Management.Accounts.list();
  if (accounts.getItems()) {
    var firstAccountId = accounts.getItems()[0].getId();

    var webProperties = Analytics.Management.Webproperties.list(firstAccountId);
    if (webProperties.getItems()) {

      var firstWebPropertyId = webProperties.getItems()[0].getId();
      var profiles = Analytics.Management.Profiles.list(firstAccountId, firstWebPropertyId);

      if (profiles.getItems()) {
        var firstProfile = profiles.getItems()[0];
        return firstProfile;

      } else {
        throw new Error('No views (profiles) found.');
      }
    } else {
      throw new Error('No webproperties found.');
    }
  } else {
    throw new Error('No accounts found.');
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you try the run command in the google app script environment?  To get all the authorizations for the script activated.

Comment: yeah i have been running it in this - its obviously working as when i flick to the google sheet it throws the expected error but its just not managing to connect to a GA profile?!

Comment: Did you figure this one out?  You can set a breakpoint and examine the values of the variables using the debugger : https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/troubleshooting#using_the_debugger_and_breakpoints